# Generic way to parse JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, parsing

I have a JSON example

```
{
    "data":"some string data",
    "amount":200,
    "amountCurrencyList":[
        {"value":4000.0,"currency":"USD"}, 
        {"value":100.0,"currency":"GBP"}
    ]
}
```

and method that currently parse it into map-field of base object

```
public void buildDetailsFromJson(String details) {
    if (details != null) {
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> mapTypeReference = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        };
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            mapper.enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
            mapper.disable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            detailsMap = mapper.readValue(details, mapTypeReference);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Exception during JSON {} parsing! {}", details, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

JSON structure could be changed.
Idea is to have a separate method that ideally would extract needed parameter easily like `map.get(key_name)`

for example

```
public void setUpFieldsFromMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = super.detailsMap;
    this.amountCurrencyList = (ArrayList<MoneyValue>) map.get("amountCurrencyList");
    if (isNull(amountCurrencyList)) {
        throw new InvalidOrMissingParametersException("Exception during JSON parsing! Critical data is missing in DetailsMap - " + map.toString());
    }
}
```

So by getting List object by key and casting it to needed parameter. 
BUT when I try to operate with `List<MoneyValue>`

```
System.out.println(detailsObj.getAmountCurrencyList().get(0).getValue());
```

I'm getting

```
Exception: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to MoneyValue
```

Is it actually possible to achieve what I want without hard-coding TypeReference with exact params like `TypeReference<HashMap<String, List<MoneyValue>>>` ?

UPD

```
public class MoneyValue {
@NotNull
private BigDecimal value;
@NotNull
private String currency;
```

EventDetails class

```
public class SomeEventDetails extends BaseEventDetails implements EventDetails {

private ArrayList<MoneyValue> amountCurrencyList;

@Override
public void setUpFieldsFromMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = super.detailsMap;
    this.amountCurrencyList = (ArrayList<MoneyValue>) map.get("amountCurrencyList");
    if (isNull(amountCurrencyList)) {
        throw new InvalidOrMissingParametersException("Exception during JSON parsing! Critical data is missing in DetailsMap - " + map.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How about a constructor for MoneyValue (or some static builder) that builds it from a `Map<String,Object>`?

Comment: Please share a code of `MoneyValue` class

Comment: why don't you create a class for all the input data e.g. `DetailsData`? In this case you will be able to make your own `JsonDeserializer<DetailsData>` and parse input data as you want

Comment: Updated. I have a class EventDetails which should be changed in case new details will be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a set of properties (I mean a structure of an input data) is unmodifiable we can represent it as a POJO class. Let it be `DetailsData`:

```
public class DetailsData {
  private String data;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private List<MoneyValue> amountCurrencyList;

  /*getters, setters, constructors*/

  public DetailsData() {
  }

  @JsonProperty("amountCurrencyList")
  private void deserializeMoneyValue(List<Map<String, Object>> data) {
    if (Objects.isNull(amountCurrencyList)) {
        amountCurrencyList = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        amountCurrencyList.clear();
    }        
    MoneyValue moneyValue;
    for (Map<String, Object> item : data) {
      moneyValue = new MoneyValue(getValue(item.get("value")),
          (String) item.get("currency"));
      amountCurrencyList.add(moneyValue);
    }
  }

  private BigDecimal getValue(Object value) {
    BigDecimal result = null;
    if (value != null) {
      if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
        result = (BigDecimal) value;
      } else if (value instanceof BigInteger) {
        result = new BigDecimal((BigInteger) value);
      } else if (value instanceof Number) {
        result = new BigDecimal(((Number) value).doubleValue());
      } else {
        throw new ClassCastException("Invalid value");
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

As you can see here is a method `deserializeMoneyValue` annotated as a JSON property. So for an ObjectMapper it will serve as a custom deserializer. `getValue` method is necessary because Jackson works in such a way so the value will be deserialized in a class that is satisfies a size of the value. e.g. if the value = "100" it will be deserialized as `Integer`, if value = "100.0" - as `Double` and so on. Actually this method you can make `static` and move into some util class.
Summarizing that, you can change `buildDetailsFromJson` in the following manner:

```
public void buildDetailsFromJson(String details) {
    if (details != null) {        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            mapper.enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
            mapper.disable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            // assuming the eventDetails is an instance of DetailsData
            eventDetails = mapper.readValue(details, DetailsData.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Exception during JSON {} parsing! {}", details, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the EventDetail class:

```
public class SomeEventDetails extends BaseEventDetails implements EventDetails {

    private List<MoneyValue> amountCurrencyList;

    @Override
    public void setUpFieldsFromMap() {
        this.amountCurrencyList = super.eventDetails.getAmountCurrencyList();
        if (isNull(amountCurrencyList)) {
            throw new InvalidOrMissingParametersException("Exception during JSON parsing! Critical data is missing in DetailsMap - " + super.eventDetails.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's the case - JSON structure can be changed in a way, that new fields can be added. That's why I'm trying to figure out some easy editable solution

Comment: Actually that's enough. With configuring mapper to ignore unknown fields we will have only needed in our class. True. Thanks for point me at my mistake. Don't know why I've tried to make things more complicated :D

Comment: Glad I got to help you! If the goal is to get currency list it's really enough